# Multiple rewrite conditions and folder exception in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on my website and facing some problems with `.htaccess` files. 
I got a main directory(in my case public_html) with sub directory called `admin`.
What I'm trying to manage is that if end-user enters URL like `example.com/admin`, he will be redirected to that `admin` directory which contains login form, custom index.php file and so on.
If other url has been entered, it needs to be checked by some conditions.
Here are my .htaccess files:

For main directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?menu=$1&op=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?menu=$1&op=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For admin directory:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Right now main directories `.htaccess` file works properly after entering urls like:

```
example.com/news/article/4
example.com/news/list
```

example.com/home

but if I enter `example.com/admin`, its associated with third rewrite rule and thinks that 'admin' is a menu link.

I have tried different exceptions, but nothing worked for me, `admin` is still associated with menu not directory. Maybe my main .htaccess file has some mistakes? Could some one suggest me the right solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any `.htaccess` in `admin` directory. Just have these rules in root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&op=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&op=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Wow..it worked and root .htaccess file now looks quite better! Thank you!